# RexEx for first half of Email match

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to match to the first half of an email address.
Legitimate values for the domain are:

- First.Name
- First.Middle.Name
- First.I.Name
- First.I.N.Name (here there is no limit to the number of initials but the most I have seen are 2)
  Also in some cases an _ has been used I think to substitute an apostrophe as in O_Neil

The expression I have at the moment is [a-zA-Z_]+(.[a-zA-Z_])* but this is not working... Any help appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the email can be entered in any case.... it does not need to follow the Upper/Lower convetion that I have above. e.g. first.name, FIRST.NAME and fIrST.naME would all be legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
(
    [A-Z][a-z]+\.       # first name
    (
        [A-Z][a-z]+\.|  # middle name or
        ([A-Z]\.){1,2}  # initial
    )
    [A-Z][a-z]+         # last name
)
```

You can add `_` and `@` characters where necessary.

Comment: Thanks.... while waiting I also came up with [a-z]+([a-z_])+\.([a-z])+((\.)?[a-z_]+)* which seems to work also.

Comment: As long as it does the job :) BTW, if you don't use it already, have a look at [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com). It's very helpful for quickly creating regular expressions.

Comment: Regexpal looks good. A minefield of info. Thanks. I've used your answer. Its looks more robust than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following regex:

```
/^([^@]*)/
```

It will match everything before `@` sign.